# Resetting glossary glsdisplayfirst

Tags: formatting, glossaries

I'm working on a paper that includes a summary at the start of the document, and I would like to reset the `glsdisplayfirst` properties somehow, so that my glossary entries and acronyms are defined both in the summary and in the document itself. I can't seem to find a way to do this, so help is appreciated.

Example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\glossfirstformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glsdisplayfirst}[4]{\glossfirstformat{#1#4}}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{term}{name={Term}, text={term}, description={A term that obviously needs explaining in the glossary}}
\newacronym{test}{TIAT}{This Is A Test}

\begin{document}

\section{Summary}
The first occurence of \gls{term} should be \textit{italic}. 
The second occurence of \gls{term} shouldn't, though. 

The full definition of \gls{test} should show just the first time, and the abbreviation afterwards, like this: \gls{test}.

\section{Rest}
The first occurence of \gls{term} should - again - be \textit{italic}. 
The rest of the occurences of \gls{term} throughout the rest of the document shouldn't, though. 

The full definition of \gls{test} should - again - show just the first time, and the abbreviation afterwards, like this: \gls{test}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The package `glossaries` provides a macro called `\glsresetall`. This does exactly what you want.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\glossfirstformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glsdisplayfirst}[4]{\glossfirstformat{#1#4}}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{term}{name={Term}, text={term}, description={A term that obviously needs explaining in the glossary}}
\newacronym{test}{TIAT}{This Is A Test}

\begin{document}
\section{Summary}
The first occurence of \gls{term} should be \textit{italic}. 
The second occurence of \gls{term} shouldn't, though. 

The full definition of \gls{test} should show just the first time, and the abbreviation afterwards, like this: \gls{test}.
\glsresetall
\section{Rest}
The first occurence of \gls{term} should - again - be \textit{italic}. 
The rest of the occurences of \gls{term} throughout the rest of the document shouldn't, though. 

The full definition of \gls{test} should - again - show just the first time, and the abbreviation afterwards, like this: \gls{test}.

\section{Reset one}
\glsreset{test}
You can also only reset the \gls{test} entry which should now display the full definition, the \gls{term} entry should not be affected.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]